# UpdateResource doesn't work with lpType as string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi

P/Invoke declarations:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, IntPtr lpType, IntPtr lpName, ushort wLanguage, byte[] lpData, uint cbData);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, int lpName, ushort wLanguage, byte[] lpData, uint cbData);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, bool bDeleteExistingResources);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);
```

My code:

```
var hUpdate = BeginUpdateResource(FilePath, false);
var BMP = File.ReadAllBytes(BmpPath);
UpdateResource(hUpdate, "2", 123, 1033, BMP, (uint)BMP.Length);
UpdateResource(hUpdate, "#2", 123, 1033, BMP, (uint)BMP.Length);
UpdateResource(hUpdate, "RT_BITMAP", 123, 1033, BMP, (uint)BMP.Length);
UpdateResource(hUpdate, "BITMAP", 123, 1033, BMP, (uint)BMP.Length);
EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, false);
```

None of the above `UpdateResource` calls work. They add the new resource under a new resource type named `#2, RT_BITMAP, BITMAP` instead of updating the existing resource.

In the P/Invoke declaration of `UpdateResource`, if I overload `string lpType` to `IntPtr lpType` and pass it a `new IntPtr(2)`, everything works but I don't want to use this solution because sometimes I also need `string lpType` for custom resource types and overloading will require too many changes in my current code design.

MSDN:

> lpType [in]
>
> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The resource type to be updated. Alternatively, rather than a pointer,
>   this parameter can be MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), where ID is an integer
>   value representing a predefined resource type. If the first character
>   of the string is a pound sign (#), then the remaining characters
>   represent a decimal number that specifies the integer identifier of
>   the resource type. For example, the string "#258" represents the
>   identifier 258.

Any idea why can't I update the existing bitmap by passing `lpType` a string? I am doing exactly what's stated in MSDN.

PS: I **absolutely** need to pass `lpType` a string, can't use `IntPtr` by overloading because of the reason stated above (too many changes required for current code design).

Comment: Yes I know, from the question: `overloading will require too many changes in my current code design.`

Isn't there a way to do it with just a string? There are more reasons which I can't explain clearly to why I can't use a IntPtr.

Comment: The only possible thing you could do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely MSDN is wrong.

The documentation for the `lpName` parameter says "when creating a new resource do not use a string that begins with a '#' character for this parameter".  I imagine the same restriction applies to `lpType`.

You can fix this without altering the structure of the rest of your code.

Define both overloads of `UpdateResource` but make them private and rename them (maybe to `UpdateResourceW`).

Then define your own public `UpdateResource` function in C#.  This should inspect the `lpType` parameter.  If the type begins with a `#` convert it to an integer and call the `IntPtr lpType` overload, otherwise use the `string lpType` overload.

Thus you can use strings for resource types throughout your code, and handle this detail in a single place.

Comment: So simple. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: MSDN is wrong about this too: `when creating a new resource do not use a string that begins with a '#' character for this parameter` The statement implies that when not creating a new resource, that is when replacing an existing resource, the `#` character can be used. But even that doesn't update the existing resource, it adds another one with the name `#123`.

Comment: @user3666697, did you manged to solved it, i tried, but the resulting exe shows "Invalid Picture" error :( any help? please?